# Bluetooth: Remove a device from bonding table on windows

Tags: .net, windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

**Is it possible to remove an entry from the bluetooth bonding table programmatically?**

Preferably, we'd like to do this with a .NET Framework app but are also interested if this could be done with a UWP App as an alternative. The bonding table concerned is the one on the windows device running the app (which would be the peripheral).

If it's not possible to do so programmatically, how does windows handle the entries on the bond table filling up? The bond table on our master device is setup to just drop the oldest entry. Does windows have a bond table limit and what happens when the number of bonded devices exceeds that limit?

Comment: Yes, BluetoothDeleteDevice function is what you need. Also there is something like BluetoothDevice Unpair() method  for WinRT. There is no limits for paired devices because ther are stored in Windows Registry (except limit of free disk space to store Registry files).

Comment: I see pairing and bonding used interchangeably, but as I understand it pairing is short term (SKT) and bonding is long term (LKT). So, when I use the unpair method, that also drops the long term key, right?

Comment: Yes, correct. Actualy for Windows it does not matter. So basically on Windows platforms it all called Pairing.